# Allow access to page based on specific location

Tags: javascript, php, html, security

Is it possible to make a page only accessible if the user is within a 10 meter radius of a certain geo coordinate?

I know it is possible to redirect a user based on their country or city, but can I make it so that it redirects based on their locality or an even smaller region such as a 10m2 area?

Comment: you need to use geolocation api...

Comment: You gotta understand that if you do your redirects with JavaScript it is going to be accessible to anybody.

Comment: Its doable, but you will need GPS for that as the accuracy is between 2 to 6 meters. eg you will need to enter the exact coordinates for your web server, and then on a smart phone device or PC you need GPS turned on. You then grab the GPS cordinates and using PHP you could compare the Distance Length. You could stick (0.01) for meters in this example distance locator. PS. With HTML5 Geoloaction am not sure that will work because it gets the location ofthe router you are connected. ---  http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php